# Java CSV Regex matching per element for validation of each cell

Tags: java, regex, csv, validation, mapreduce

Ok, so I have this issue that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

what I'm trying to do, is the following:

read in a CSV file line by line, split it up at the comma and pass it into a hashmap and then carry out some operations.

I'm effectively trying to replicate some of the behaviours of map reduce in java.

Now, what I have so far is:

```
public class mapper {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //file reading - here.

    Scanner filePathInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filePath = filePathInput.nextLine();
    File file = new File(filePath);


    if (file.isFile()) {
        Scanner fileInput = null;
        try {
            fileInput = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<String> lineBuffer = new ArrayList<>();

        while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fileInput.nextLine();
          //  char ch = line.charAt(0);
            lineBuffer.add(line);

            //String[] values = line.split(",");
           // Map<String, Integer> reducer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            // parse the line here
            //System.out.println(values);
        }
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<FlightData>> test = mapper(lineBuffer);

    }

}
```

I then have the mapper to the hash map down:

```
   public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<FlightData>> mapper(ArrayList<String> lineBuffer) {

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<FlightData>> mapdata = new HashMap<>();

    for (String flightData: lineBuffer) {
        String[] str = flightData.split(",");
        FlightData flight = new FlightData(str[0], str[1], str[2].toCharArray(),str[3].toCharArray(), new Date(Long.valueOf(str[4])), Long.valueOf(str[5]).longValue());
        mapdata.get(flight.getFlightID());
        if(mapdata.containsKey(flight.getFlightID())){
            mapdata.get(flight.getFlightID()).add(flight);
        }
        else {
            ArrayList<FlightData> noID = new ArrayList<>();
            noID.add(flight);
            mapdata.put(flight.getFlightID(), noID);
        }

    }

  System.out.println(mapdata);

    return mapdata;

}
```

I have my flight data object defined here with the getters etc:

```
public class FlightData {

private String passengerID;
private String flightID;
private char[] fromID = new char[3];
private char[] tooID = new char[3];
public Date departTime;
public long flightTimeMins;
public Date arrivalTime;

//Constucter;
    public FlightData(String passengerID, String flightID, char[] fromID, char[] tooID, Date departTime, long flightTimeMins) {
        setPassengerID(passengerID);
        setFlightID(flightID);
        setFromID(fromID);
        setTooID(tooID);
        setFlightTimeMins(flightTimeMins);
        setDepartTime(departTime);
        setArrivalTime(arrivalTime);
```

However, I am having an issue is, how do I carry out the validation:

presumably I need to create a class that contains all of my patterns and all of the logic for that right? and just call it when needed?

I have set up a basic class for this:

```
public class Validation {

public static void validate(String theReg, String str2Check) {

    final Pattern PtnPassenger = Pattern.compile(theReg);
    final Pattern PtnFlight = Pattern.compile(theReg);
    final Pattern PtnFrom = Pattern.compile(theReg);
    final Pattern PtnToo = Pattern.compile(theReg);

    Matcher regexMatcher = PtnPassenger.matcher(str2Check);

    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        if (regexMatcher.group().length() != 0) {

            System.out.println(regexMatcher.group().trim());
        }



    }
}
```

**But, how to I do the following:**

1. set it up so that as each line is read it it checks, it is empty?
2. set it up so that then, if its not it checks that "cell" against the pattern, moves onto the next and repeats step 1

so for example, each line should contain following comma separated data:

> PID, FID, FromID, TooID, time(linux epoch) minutes e.g:
>
> BWI0520BG0,   MOO1786A, MAD, FRA, 1420563408, 184
>
> so, for example, for pID I would need a regex like this:
>
> ```
> [A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}
> ```

but, how do I check each element? should I do this before I pass them into the hash map? or?

Any help would be great.

Cheers

Comment: If it is a fixed number of fields and you don't need to worry about delimiter escaping, you could just split it up, then validate each separately, or you can write a big regex for the entire line to test it. And... what to do if it is invalid ?

Comment: @sln yeah, it should never be more than the above columns. 

ahh, you mean one to encompass the entire line? hmm...

I'm not sure how well that would work for me. but maybe. 

and ideally I would simply write it to a text file or something.